# IllegalArgumentException Cucumber Custom Params Java

Tags: java, cucumber-java

I'm getting a runtime CucumberException:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to invoke com.inin.testing.cucumber.stepdefs.ui.chat.ChatRosterStepDefs.a_splat_is_displayed_on_the_groups_tab_of_the_chat_roster(String,String) in file: *******/cucumber-tests/target/classes/, caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

My feature step is:  `Then a splat is not displayed on the "user" tab of our roster`

My custom param for cucumber expressions is:

```
registry.defineParameterType(new ParameterType<>(
                "isOrIsNot",                     // name
                "is|is not",                     // regexp
                boolean.class,                   // type
                (String arg) -> "is".equals(arg) // transformer function
        ));
```

And lastly my Gherkin:

```
@Then("a splat {isOrIsNot} displayed on the {string} tab of our roster")
```

I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong, is my custom param defined incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Well for anyone wondering, I simply needed to change the custom param definition to String.class, and have the function return the arg!